# how to save JWT token on client, using Hapi js in node.?

Tags: node.js, cookies, jwt, hapi.js

I want to authenticate a user using JWT token. after a successful validation i am creating a jwt token. I have got some where on internet that i have to send this token to client.how can i save this token and how i can send this token to every request or the token will be automatically attached to the request header? if not then how can i attach this token in request header?. I am using Hapi js with node.

below is my code:

```
var validateUser = function(request, reply) {
  var email = request.payload.email;
  var userPassword = request.payload.password;

  // get user form database
  var user = users[email];

  // check if exists
  if(!user){
    var errMsg = 'User not found';
    reply.view('login',{errMsg:errMsg});
  }
  else {
    // validate the user
    bcrypt.compare(userPassword, user.password, function(err, isValid) {

      if(!isValid){
          var errMsg = 'Wrong username or password!';
          reply.view('login',{errMsg:errMsg});
      }
      else {
        // if user is found and password is right
        // create a token
        var token = jwt.sign(user.id, process.env.SECRET_KEY); 
// I want to send this token to client, and also want to save this token in header of every request.

        reply.redirect('/myNotes');
      }
    });
  }
```

}

Answer (score -1):

1)after the login store token in local storage(client side)
 
2)add token  to request header using http interceptor.
 
 are you using jquery  to call the end points then $ajax setUp is the right place.you can get more details from this post https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2131-using-jquery-ajaxsetup-to-accumulate-global-data-parameters-for-ajax-requests.htm.
 
  if you are consuming services directly from Hapi js then use onpreAuth handler.
If you need any help let me know.i am happy to help